# Topology - Open and closed sets in two different metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am currently working through some topology problems, and I would like to confirm my results just for some peace of mind!

**Statement:** *Let $(X, d_x)$ be a metric space, and $Y\subset X$ a non-empty subset. Define a metric $d_y$ on $Y$ by restriction. Then, each subset $A\subset Y $ can be viewed as a subset of $X$.*

---

**Q 1**: If $A$ is open in $X$, $A$ open in $Y$.

**A**: I obtained **TRUE**. Roughly speaking, my proof relied on showing that if we can always draw a neighbourhood in the set $A$ (*w.r.t* $X$) if we can definitely do so *w.r.t* $Y$.

---

**Q 2**: If $A$ is open in $Y$, $A$ open in $X$.

**A**: This I found **FALSE**, *example*: Let $X =\mathbb{R}, Y = [0,1]$ and $A = [0, 1/2)$. $A$ is open in $Y$, howevever, $A$ is **not** open in $X$.

---

**Q 3**: If $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $Y$.

**A**: This I found **TRUE**. Roughly speaking, given the preliminary conditions, $A$ cannot "lose" any of its limit points when we assess it closure in $Y$.

---

**Q 4**: If $A$ is closed in $Y$, then $A$ is closed in $X$.

**A**: This I found **FALSE**
, *example*: let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y = (0,1]$ and $A = (0,1/2].$ A is closed in $Y$, but not in $X$.

Are any of these deductions wrong? If so, how would you rectify them?

Comment: Apart from any possible errors in the details of carrying out the arguments that you merely sketched, this is fine.